# nose does not discover unit tests using load_tests

Tags: python-2.7, nose

Python 2.7.1
Nose 1.1.2

I have read related questions on this but they do not help. I have Test cases that look like the below

For example in `my_tests.py`

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    return unittest.TestSuite(MyTest() for scenario_name in list)
```

I have several such modules with load_tests method and I run them using unittest as follows

```
test_loader = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover( '.', my_pattern_var); 
test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner();
result = test_runner.run(test_loader)
sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

If I replace this with the equivalent nose code `nose.main()` it finds 0 tests.

Questions

1. How do I get nose to discover tests? ***WITHOUT*** actually losing the ability to just run my tests using python unittest. I would like to use NOSE as an addon to python unittest to get clover and coverage reports
2. How do I get it to run tests matching only a specific pattern?

Comment: is this question still relevant for you now?

Comment: Yes please. I would like the ability of NOSE finding tests that were created using the load_tests method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for getting back so late. We basically did the same thing you're trying to do here for a console script except we named all of our test modules integration_foo.py. Anyhow the solution is straightforward, just run nose programmatically.

```
import re
from nose.config import Config

TEST_REGEX = '(?:^|[\\b_\\./-])[Ll]oad'

# Change the test match pattern
nose_config = Config()
nose_config.testMatch = re.compile(TEST_REGEX)

# Specify the use of a Plugin Manager, load plugins
nose_config.plugins = BuiltinPluginManager()
nose_config.plugins.loadPlugins()

run(config=nose_config)
```

So this basic option changes the regex pattern nose is looking for from all methods labeled test to all methods labeled load. However this is not what you would need completely to run nose, it is also necessary to get some kind of parser object or pass a specific set of argv to nose.

If you want to pass a specific set of argv to be parsed by nose just do

```
run(config=nose_config, argv=["foo", "bar"])
```

Otherwise you can probably specify nose specific arguments at the command line and as long as you don't throw in anything funky nose shouldn't error.

Check out the nose source code at https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/tree/master/nose its where I got all the information I needed to write this